# When I run cidrsubnet function in terraform I am getting 'prefix extension of 3 does not accommodate a subnet numbered 8'. Why is this?

Tags: azure, terraform, subnet, cidr

code:

```js
cidrsubnet("10.1.2.0/21", 3, 8)
```

Issue:

When I run this in terraform I am getting prefix extension of 3 does not
accommodate a subnet numbered 8. Why is this? Anything below 8 works. I've followed the following example: [Configure subnets using terraform cidrsubnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65188324/configure-subnets-using-terraform-cidrsubnet) But not sure what I am missing here....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are using `cidrsubnet("10.1.2.0/21", 3, 8)`, you are adding **3 bits**. Since in binary `2 ^ 3 = 8`, you can define maximally 8 subnets in this range: 0,1,2,..., 7 with the following cidrs:

- 10.1.0.0/24
- 10.1.1.0/24
- 10.1.2.0/24
- 10.1.3.0/24
- 10.1.4.0/24
- 10.1.5.0/24
- 10.1.6.0/24
- 10.1.7.0/24

If you want to define subnets between 0 and 15, you have to use: `cidrsubnet("10.1.2.0/21", 4, 8)`, since `2 ^ 4 = 16` and you can have sixteen subnets: 0, 1, 2, ..., 15.

Comment: I am counting 8 subnets in your example. I am understanding this as 2^3=8, and my netnum is 8 in this case, so should that not work? Also you are showing 8 subnets above, what am i missing?

Comment: @shan The counting starts from `0`, not `1`. So maximum is 7, not 8.